# Как создать пользователя БД с минимумом прав и привилегий?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Установила Oracle 12c и вошла под пользователем `system`. Хочу создать своего пользователя `natali` и возникло несколько вопросов:

1. Какие права минимум нужно выдать новому пользователю?
2. Что такое табличное пространство Oracle?
3. Нужно ли создавать отдельно табличное пространство для пользователя или можно использовать пространство `USER`?

Comment: А для чего вам пользователь?

Comment: Во-первых хочу создавать таблицы и писать код под своим пользователем, а во-вторых хотя бы знать как его создавать и понять как выдавать права, и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

В версии 12c введена мултиарендная (*multitenant*) арxитектура БД, состоящая из двх частей: контейнера (CDB) и (одной или нескольких) подключаемых БД (PDB). Кратко об их отличаях в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1150815).

Содавать новых пользователей, а также вообще что-либо менять в CDB не следует.
Часто можно найти решение со скрытым параметром `_ORACLE_SCRIPT=true` для обхода ограничений при создании пользователей в CDB. Его применение строго не рекомендуется.

Поэтому, для подключения с системной учётной записью надо обязательно указывать имя службы конкретной PDB, например:

```
sqlplus -l system/<pass>@localhost:1521/pdb1
```

При установке БД былo создано стандартное табличное пространство USERS, которое будет использоваться для всех вновь создавемых пользователей БД. Создавать новое табличное пространство нет никакой необходимости.

Для выделения минимума привилегий новому пользователю, следует учесть, что через поисковики часто можно найти ранее широко используемые роли `CONNECT` и `RESOURCE`, но их уже в [версии 10g больше не рекомендовали к применению](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/authoriz.htm#DBSEG5000):

> **Note:**
> Customers **should discontinue using the CONNECT and RESOURCE roles**, as
> they will be deprecated in future Oracle Database releases.

Исходя из вышеизложенного, дайте самый минимум прав и привилегий напрямую, и далее выделяйте их по мере необходимости. То есть, сделайте следующее:

```
SQL> create user natali identified by natali quota unlimited on users;
User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table, create sequence, 
           create view, create procedure, create type to natali;
Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn natali/natali@localhost:1521/pdb1
Connected.
```

Answer (score 1):

Табличное пространство используется для логической организации хранения объектов Oracle. На данном этапе у вас нет необходимости создавать новое таблично пространство, хватит `Users`.

Для создание пользователя выполните код:

```
alter session set "_ORACLE_SCRIPT"=true; -- Без включения этого параметра мне не удалось создать пользователя в 12 Oracle.
create user natali identified by my_password
default tablespace users quota unlimited on users;
grant connect to my_user; 
grant create  table to my_user; -- создание таблиц
grant create sequence to my_user; -- создание sequence
grant create procedure to my_user; -- создание процедур
grant create type to my_user; -- создание типов
grant create trigger to my_user; -- создание триггеров
```

Обращаю внимание, что роль `connect` содержит значительно больше привилегий, чем необходимо. И в промышленных решениях рекомендуется настраивать параметры более аккуратно. Однако для текущих задач будет в самый раз.