# Не могу подключиться к БД через SQL*Plus после создания нового пользователя

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sqlplus

Для создания пользователя выполнил следующие команды через SQL*Plus:

```sql
SQL> conn / as sysdba;
Connected.

SQL> alter session set container = orclpdb;
Session altered.

SQL> create user admin identified by qq;
User created.

SQL> grant dba to admin;
Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect admin/qq@db12c;
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
```

Все время получаю такую ошибку:

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Что я делаю не так?

Tакже приложу файл tnsnames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\admin\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
PROBA.COM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PROBA)
    )
  )

LISTENER_DB12C =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

DB12C =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = db12c)
    )
  )
```

Comment: db12c - это SERVICE_NAME. Да правда ошибся в последней команде. Но и при правильном написании ошибка ORA-01017.

Comment: У вас как минимум два имени, на cdb и pdb. Какое из них?

Comment: @0xbd, прости, немного не понял... Использовал только сл. имена: SID - **db12c**, pluggable database name - **orclpdb**.

Comment: Ну попробуйте - `sqlplus admin/qq@localhost/orclpdb`. Вы уч создали в БД, не в контейнере.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо! Работает, в чем была проблема можешь подсказать?

Comment: Коротко я уже выше ответил. Напишу чуть подробне в ответе. Что вам осталось непонятным?  Я мог бы лучше объяснить, если знаю, что конкретно не понятно. Разницу между контейнером и самой БД вы понимаете?

Comment: @0xdb, видимо не совсем хорошо понимаю структуру БД и понятие контейнера. Подскажи где можно почитать про это?

Comment: Почитать можно в документации, там вполне доступно написано, с картинками. Контейнер это только оболочка, которая вмешает одну или несколько баз данных. Комманда - alter session set container ..., как раз осушествляет переход из контейнера   в конкретную БД. Пожалуйста замените картинку текстом, чтобы команды оттуда можно было копировать.

Comment: @0xdb, подскажи а чем может быть проблема при подключении через SQL Developer?  Получаю такую же ошибку (ORA-01017) при соединении через пользователя admin. Остальные настройки: hostname - localhost, port - 1521, SID - DB12C. Connection Type - Basic, Role - default.

Comment: Как и с SQL*Plus, имя сервиса - orclpdb. а не  DB12C.

Comment: Вот написал короткий ответ. Посмотрите пожалуйста. Если что-то не понятно, напишите. Цель, дать только ообщее представление о контейнерной архитектуре,  более подробно нужно только администраторам БД, коим вы не являетесь.

Comment: @VadimArtyushenko, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR С вновь созданным пользователем `admin` надо подключаться по имени сервиса самой БД (PDB), а не контейнера (CDB):

```
$ sqlplus admin/qq@localhost/orclpdb
```

Аналогично в других приложениях/инструментах, например через JDBC:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/orcldb", "admin", "qq");
```

В общем случае, разработчик должен знать только имя сервиса подключаемой БД (PDB). После подключения, он работает как с обычной БД, ничем не отличающейся от одиночной БД в ранних версиях. О существовани какого-то контейнера, который эту БД включает, он знать ничего не должен.

---

**Немного вглубь**
Начиная с версии 12 [введена мултиарендная (*multitenant*) арxитектура](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/multi/introduction-to-the-multitenant-architecture.html#GUID-267F7D12-D33F-4AC9-AA45-E9CD671B6F22), состоящая из:

- Контейнер БД (CDB *Container Database*): Это оболочка для одной или нескольких БД, служит для их управления и содержит только их общую часть. Ни пользователей приложений, ни их данных, здесь нет.
- Подключаемые БД (PDB *Pluggable Database*): Это сами БД, то есть PDB это синоним того, к чему все привыкли - *База Данных*. Здесь собственно и содержатся пользователи и данные приложений. PDB делит общую часть CDB с другими PDB, но полностью от них независима.

Первые щаги для перемещения между CDB и PDB.
Без указания имени сервиса, подключение всегда в CDB, далее, переход в заданую PDB и обратно:

```
$ sqlplus /nolog
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> show con_name
CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT

SQL> show pdbs
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO
         4 PDB2                           MOUNTED

SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;
Session altered.

SQL> show con_name
CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDB1

SQL> alter session set container=cdb$root;
Session altered.

SQL> show con_name
CON_NAME
------------------------------
CDB$ROOT
```

Comment: смотришь трансляцию и успеваешь отвечать!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Одним глазом там, одним здесь ))

Comment: Я также, довольно интересно ребята беседуют