# Создание БД в Oracle без системных таблиц

Tags: база-данных, oracle, oracle19c

Скачал 19с. После установки решил создать свои таблицы и БД, но оказалось, что БД, которая создается уже вся в системных таблица и т.д..

Кто может подсказать, как создать БД и при этом, чтобы база была пуста (без системных таблиц).

Работаю в SQL Developer.

UPD: После захода под пользователем `system` у меня такие системные таблицы сразу есть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD:

```
C:\> lsnrctl status 
Connecting to (DESCRIPTI0N=(ADDRESS=(PR0T0C0L=TCP)(H0ST=localhost)(P0RT=1521))) STATUS of the LISTENER
Alias LISTENER
Version TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date 13-1UL-2020 23:56:07
Uptime 0 days 4 hr. 20 min. 28 sec
Trace Level off
Security ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP OFF
Listener Parameter File C:\App\db_home\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File C:\App\Myoracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKT0P-FRAN7VN\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))) (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=DESKTOP-FRAN7VN)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_^ Services Summary___
Service "52448234712340b69f274bcc790ecfe0" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
Service "c908dd6e99b547e4a6f598505d671dcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
Service "oraclel" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "oraclel", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
Service "orclXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
Service "orclpdb" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service... 
The command completed successfully
```

UPD: Файл tsnname.ora (прим.ред.: см. историю правок)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110592/discussion-on-question-by-juniorlittle----oracle---).

Answer (score 2):

> После установки решил создать свои таблицы и БД, но оказалось, что БД, которая создается уже вся в системных таблица и т.д.

В инсталяторе была отмечена радио-кнопка "(х) Create and configure a database". То есть, БД была создана сразу же при установке продукта.

БД состоит из двх частей: контейнера (CDB) и (одной или нескольких) подключаемых БД (PDB). Кратко об их отличаях уже [повествовал в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1150768).

Подключение с системной учётной записью без указания конкретного PDB осуществляется к CDB.
Здесь можно администрировать существующие PDB или создавать новые. Было бы удивительно, не увидеть здесь системных таблиц.
**Важно**: Содавать новых пользователей, новые таблицы, или что-то менять в CDB не следует.

Следуюший шаг - создать нового пользователя БД. Учитывая  то, что создание нового пользователя, веделения ему прав и привилегий в продуктивной среде, занимаются администраторы БД, то далее следует читать **только** для БД, создаваемых в тестовых целях (для дома, для семьи).

---

Для создания нового пользователя в PDB, надо сначала туда перейти:

```
$ sqlplus /nolog

SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> show pdbs
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         2 PDB$SEED                       READ ONLY  NO
         3 PDB1                           READ WRITE NO

SQL> alter session set container=pdb1;
Session altered.

SQL> show con_name
CON_NAME
------------------------------
PDB1
```

Теперь, в основном, две возможности:

1. **Рекомендуемая**: создать пользователя с минимальным набором прав и привилегий, далее выделять их по мере необходимости.
2. Или создать сразу административного пользователя, который может всё (**Осторожно!** В БД нет предупреждения: "Вы действительно хотите ...")

Нормальный пользователь (*один из нас*):

```
SQL> create user iam identified by iam;
User created.

SQL> alter user iam quota unlimited on users;
User altered.

SQL> grant create session, create table, create view,
           create procedure, create sequence to iam;
Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn iam/iam@localhost/pdb1
Connected.
```

Административный пользователь (*и Бог и Царь*):

```
SQL> create user iam identified by iam;
User created.

SQL> grant dba to iam;
Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn iam/iam@localhost/pdb1
Connected.
```